# Unit test ViewChild with mat sort and set content, Jasmine and Karma

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, angular6, karma-jasmine

I have `ViewChild` with `set content`. 
I would like to know how you can test this piece of code using Unit test.

This image is code coverage

[image]

```js
  @ViewChild(MatSort) set content(content: ElementRef) {
    this.sort = content;
    Iif (this.sort) {
      this.historyReport.sort = this.sort;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add MatSortModule in the dependency, will help you

````
      imports: [MatSortModule],
      declarations: [],
      providers: [
      ]
    }).compileComponents();```
````